# Snow Leopard Server VPN service - Health control check: server is sick

Tags: vpn, osx-snow-leopard

Looking at the VPN service log on my Snow Leopard server, it spews the following messages over and over:

> 2010-11-16 15:04:49 JST   Health control check: server is sick...
>     2010-11-16 15:04:50 JST   Health control check: server is back to normal...

The VPN service won't let me log in either. What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the `racoon` service might be going crazy in the background and kill it, optionally restart the VPN service.

---

*(asked and answered this question as part of documenting a problem I just fixed and couldn't find a solution for on Google)*

In my case the `racoon` went into limbo, eating up CPU, after trying to connect to the VPN using a Windows XP client (possibly with incorrect settings).

Comment: I like that, as a OS X server admin myself, I find it totally normal to see amusing console messages in my logs and to say things like "Check if the racoon might be going crazy in the background and kill it" :)

Comment: @Jack That's part of the fun of being a *NIX admin. All poor Windows admins get to say are things like "The WDF service didn't respool the HHBVS correctly after WA BSODed…" ;o)